# PCRE regex whitespace

Tags: regex, pcre, pcregrep

I am trying to write a regex to pull all **non-comment** and **non-empty** lines from /etc/samba/smb.conf.  Comments are lines that:

1. start with #
2. start with ;
3. start with any amount of whitespace followed immediately by either # or ;

I tried the following, but it did not properly handle comment type 3.

```
grep -P '^\s*[^#;]' /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

This one worked for all 3 types of comments:

```
grep -P '^\s*[^#;\s]' /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Can you explain why adding \s to the character class successfully filtered out comment type 3?

Comment: @vks no it shouldn't, this one works `cat smb.conf |grep -P '\s*[#;]' -v`. Read about `^` in begin of pattern and inside of character group defintion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is [partial matches](https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/10) as you have not used an end anchor `$`.

In case of example 3

```
      ;
```

There will be partial matching upto `;` done by `\s*`.In the other regex you have disabled `\s` so it will not capture the space and partial match is disabled.

The correct regex here is

```
 (?m)^(?!\s*[#;]).+$
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/11)

Comment: it's wrong, test on my file not filter lines like `<spaces>#fsdfs` (with spaces at begin)

Comment: i tell to you actual result of command output, that they didn't do what  OP expect.

Comment: This answer still matches lines that begin with spaces followed by #.

Comment: @vks check the output [here](http://pastebin.com/CMq44Dj9) and [here](http://pastebin.com/V7pu5rpV) , i'm not care about regex101 matching, i'm check that in console

Comment: @vks with the `m` flag, the first answer incorrectly matches comment type 3. The second answer incorrectly matches comment types 1 and 2.

Comment: @vks It's correct now, except that it includes blank lines. I updated the original question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

`[^...]` means does not match any of the characters given at the place of `...`.

You need: `^\s*[#;]`.

Comment: This is incorrect.Read the question carefully. ` pull all non-comment lines from /etc/samba/smb.conf.`

Comment: in case of grep, `^` not needed, `cat smb.conf |grep -P '\s*[#;]' -v` . Proposed answer with OP question provide wrong result

Comment: and PS `^` at start of string - means start of line, read about `^...$`. So answer is completely wrong

Comment: @Reishin please read about character classes before classifing this answer as "completely wrong". Thanks!